# C++ trying to read in malformed CSV with erroneous commas

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to make a simple CSV file parser to transfer a large number of orders from an order system to an invoicing system. The issue is that the CSV which i am downloading has erroneous commas which are sometimes present in the name field and so this throws the whole process off.

The company INSISTS, which is really starting to piss me off, that they are simply copying data they receive into the CSV and so it's valid data.

Excel mostly seems to interpret this correctly or at least puts the data in the right field, my program however doesn't. I opened the CSV in notepad++ and there is no quotes around strings just raw string separated by commas.

This is currently how i am reading the file.

```
  int main()
  {
    string t;
    getline(cin, t);
    string Output;
    string path = "in.csv";
    ifstream input(path);
    vstring readout;
    vstring contact, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, DueDate, Description, Quantity, UnitAmount, AccountCode, TaxType, Currency, Allocator, test, Backup, AllocatorBackup;
    vector<int> read, add, total;
    if (input.is_open()) {
        for (string line; getline(input, line); ) {
            auto arr = explode(line, ',');
            contact.push_back(arr[7]); // Source site is the customer in this instance.
            InvoiceNumber.push_back(arr[0]); // OrderID will be invoice number
            InvoiceDate.push_back(arr[1]); // Perchase date
            DueDate.push_back(arr[1]); // Same as order date
            Description.push_back(arr[0]);
            Quantity.push_back(arr[0]);
            UnitAmount.push_back(arr[10]); // The Total
            AccountCode.push_back(arr[7]); // Will be set depending on other factors - But contains the site of perchase
            Currency.push_back(arr[11]); // EUR/GBP
            Allocator.push_back(arr[6]); // This will decide the VAT treatment normally. 
            AllocatorBackup.push_back(arr[5]); // This will decide VAT treatment if the column is off by one.
            Backup.push_back(arr[12]);
            TaxType = Currency;
        }
    }
      return 0;
  }

  vstring explode(string const & s, char delim) {
    vstring result;
    istringstream q(s);
    for (string token; getline(q, token, delim); ) {
        result.push_back(move(token));
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Vstring is a compiler macro i created to save me typing vector so often, so it's the same thing.

The issue is when i come across one of the fields with the comma in it (normally the name field which is [3]) it of cause pushes everything back by one so account code becomes [8] etc.. This is extremely troublesome as it's difficult to tell weather or not i am dealing with correct data in the next field or not in some cases.

So two questions:

1) Is there any simple way in which i could detect this anomaly and correct for it that i've missed? I of cause do try to check in my loop where i can if valid data is where it's expected to be, but this is becoming messy and does not cope with more than one comma.

2) Is the company correct in telling me that it's "Expected behavior" to allow commas entered by a customer to creep into this CSV without being processed or have they completely misunderstood the CSV "standard"?

Comment: In valid CSV the field should be quoted when it includes delimiter characters. Is that so with your data?

Comment: You seem to know how many fields there will be on a line, so if that one field is the only issue then parse the fields before it then work backwards to parse the fields after it, and what's left is the field you left out.

Comment: @boxmein no, sadly there is nothing so simple, the commas are just sitting in the middle of data with no clear visual way to tell if it's a new field or just data. There are no quotes in the file at all.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The issue with this is that i'm trying to work with a price field, and the field directly after the price field happens to be "processed time" which can look remarkably similar to a price. So i am having trouble telling which i am reading. Or did i misunderstand what you said?

Comment: 1 - There's no simple way, unless you know which fields can be corrupted and in exactly what ways
2 - The company is wrong. If the delimiter appears as part of a field, the whole field must be surrounded by quotes

Comment: @EyalK.   Yeah this is what i thought/was expecting. I just thought before i start becoming more assertive that this is a malformed file i would check to make sure i've not had a serious error of concept. I do know which field is corrupted every time, however this splits into the next field, and in some cases the field after that. so i'm having trouble figuring out exactly how much corruption has occurred.

Comment: @user3407675 - do you know what tools they are using to generate the CSV? Because obviously their tools aren't quoting things they way they should, which is the root of your problems. If you find out what their tool chain is, perhaps you can help them make better use of it.

Comment: @MichaelKohne This was my first instinct, i made a very precise bug report to them and initially was greeted well, now they are being very obstinate and un-receptive to feedback. They are adamantly denying this is a bug which is Wearing very thin. From how their site works it looks like just some php generating an output from their database. I tried to suggest some code they could use which would filter this out, and again got nowhere sadly.

Comment: This may help to illustrate what I was thinking. Apologies for the terrible code, but work beckons. Basically, parse from the beginning to the field you have a problem with, parse from the end to right after the field you have a problem with, and what's left is the problem field. Perhaps not a workable solution, but I wanted to figure out how it might work. :) https://ideone.com/cR1FfE I agree with everyone else, extra commas and no quotes around fields make your csv malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retired Ninja mentioned in the comments that one constraint would be to parse all fields either side of the 'problem field' first, and then put the remaining data into the problem field. This is the best approach if you know which field might contain corruption. If you don't know which field could be corrupted, you still have options though!

You know:

1. The number of fields that should be present
2. Something about the type of data in each of those fields.

If you codify the types of the fields (implement classes for different data types, so your vectors of strings would become vectors of OrderIDs or Dates or Counts or....), you can test different concatenations (joining adjacent fields that are separated by a comma) and score them according to how many of the fields pass some data validation. You then choose the best scoring interpretation of the data. This would build some data validation into the process, and make everything a bit more robust.

Comment: This actually does sound like a great option, as i also then get an opportunity to filter out anymore toxic/malformed data and ensure that i am not going to parse anything which could be dangerous and reduce chance of sending invalid invoices around. I hadn't thought of doing it in this way yet, i'd been so obsessed with trying to figure out what was where from a presumption. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

'csv' is not that well defined. There is the *standard* way, where ',' seperates the columns and '\n' the rows. Sometimes ' " ' is used to handle these symbols inside a field. But Excel includes them only if a Control Character is involved.

Here the definition from Wiki.

> RFC 4180 formalized CSV. It defines the MIME type "text/csv", and CSV files that follow its rules should be very widely portable. Among its requirements:
>
> -MS-DOS-style lines that end with (CR/LF) characters (optional for the
> last line).
>
> -An optional header record (there is no sure way to detect
> whether it is present, so care is required when importing).
>
> -Each record "should" contain the same number of comma-separated fields.
>
> -Any field *may* be quoted (with double quotes).
>
> -Fields containing a line-break, double-quote or commas should be quoted. (If > they are not, the file will likely be impossible to process correctly).
>
> -A (double)quote character in a field must be represented by two (double) quote > characters.
> [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Keep in mind that Excel has different settings on different systems/system language settings. It might be, that their Excel is parsing it correctly, but somewhere else it isn't.

For Example, in countries like Germany there is ';' used to seperate the columns. The decimal seperators differ as well.

1.5 << english

1,5 << german

Same goes for the thousand seperator.

1,000,000 << english

1.000.000 << german

or

1 000 000 << also german

Now, Excel also has different csv export settings like .csv(Seperated values), .csv(MACINTOSH) and .csv(MS-DOS) so I guess there can be differences too.

Now for your questions, in my opinion they are not clearly wrong with what they are doing with their files. But you should think about discussing about a (E)BNF with them. Here some Links:

[BNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)
[EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

It is a grammar on which you decide on and with clear definitions the code should be no problem. I know customers can block something like this, because they don't want to have extra work, but it is simply the best solution. If you want ' " ' in your file, they should provide you somehow. I don't know how they copy their data, but it should also be some kind of program (I don't think they do this per hand?), so your code and their code should use the same (E)BNF which you decide on together with them.

Comment: From what I remember the Macintosh and MS-DOS settings just affect line endings, not actual fields.

Comment: Actually it is about tab characters, line breaks, and other characters(special characters), just looked it up. 
If interested: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Save-a-workbook-to-text-format-txt-or-csv-3e9a9d6c-70da-4255-aa28-fcacf1f081e6?omkt=en-GB&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: I think see the issue now. It seems rather immature for them to disobey a commonly accepted template system however. I am not confident that they will be willing to accommodate this given that they refused to just sanitize commas, and it's a button on a service commonly used by others. But thank you for the clarification, at least i now understand their position (And thus by extension mine)

Comment: I know this can be difficult. I had a long long long discussion with my boss about this topic, because he wanted the csv File we wrote to work on every computer (in any country) without the user to do anything. In the end I too had to manage it somehow, but mostly I try going for the clean solution instead of workarounds. Also even with the solution above there can be errors, maybe communicating this can somwhow convince them to cooperate.